# How to check an array for string or char

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

From the command line, I want to write a for loop that will detect if there is a string or char in the array from the command line arguments.

For example, a person enters `4.3, 5, 99, 0.1, w, 4, 2.43`. Right when the loop  detects the char w, it will print "Error." Same thing goes for if the input was `4.3, 5, 99, 0.1, wasabi, 4, 2.43`; when the loop detects the string `wasabi` it will display an error message. The thing that I cannot figure out is how to write the loop so that it detects ANY char or string, no matter where it is on the array. This is what I have so far:

```
//check for a string or char in array
void checkForWord(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++)
    {
        if ()
        {
            //do something..
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Well, all the `argv` entries are strings by definition. I guess you actually mean whether the string can be parsed as a number. Assuming you want to parse them as `float` then use something like [`strtof`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) on each of the `argv` strings. The return value and return parameters of `strtof` can tell you if it was successfully converted and hence a valid float or not.

Comment: Do you want your answer in C or C++? They'll be different. Choose one or the other.

Comment: C++ please. I am trying to get the for loop but with not much luck.

Comment: That is because there is no code in your for loop, only a comment. And that `if` is not valid code either.

Comment: What if the input is `4....3, 5` - would that be an error? And what about `4.3,5` (i.e. no space) - is that an error

Comment: You should define your correct input more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char* const* argv)
{
    // first, concatenate the command line arguments into a continuous buffer
    std::string buffer;
    auto sep = "";
    for(int i = 1 ; i < argc ; ++i)
    {
        buffer += sep;
        buffer += argv[i];
        sep = " ";
    }

    // now turn the buffer into a string stream
    auto stream = std::istringstream(buffer);

    // now stream in my numbers, delimited by commas
    std::string val_buffer;
    while (std::getline(stream, val_buffer, ','))
    {
        // make a new string stream, just to parse the text into a number
        auto num_stream = std::istringstream(val_buffer);
        double val = 0;
        if (num_stream >> val)
        {
            // parsed correctly. now let's do something with it
            std::cout << "found a value: " << val << std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            // whatever that was, it wasn't a number
            std::cout << "found a something I didn't like: " << val_buffer << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (stream.bad())
    {
        std::cout << "something bad happened" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

results when executed with command line `4.3, 5, 99, 0.1, wasabi, 4, 2.43`:

```
found a value: 4.3
found a value: 5
found a value: 99
found a value: 0.1
found a something I didn't like:  wasabi
```

results without the wasabi:

```
found a value: 4.3
found a value: 5
found a value: 99
found a value: 0.1
found a value: 4
found a value: 2.43
```

Comment: Can you explain the part where the actual checking is performed? I don't quite understand the process.

Comment: @yurtmama num_stream >> val attempts to parse a number into val. If it fails, it sets the failbit in the stream. The stream object has a bool conversion operator so you can use it in an if statement. It if evaluates to true, there's no failure recorded. If the stream evaluates to false, it means it failed at something (in this case, parsing the number)

Comment: Any way you can post an updated code that's "dumbed down" per se?.. I'm kinda new to C++ so your code is pretty confusing to me

Comment: Oh, and when I originally posted the question I didn't mean to include commas in the inputs. Just spaces between each input, if that changes anything.

Comment: Yes, that changes a lot. Will have a look tomorrow.@yurtmama

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)  // Don't do argc - 1 when using <
{
    string s = argv[i];
    for (auto c : s)
    {
        if (c != ',' && c != '.' && !isdigit(c))
        {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This will accept input like `4....3,,,,, 5, 99, 0.1, 4, 2.43` as the code doesn't check the number of `.` and the number of `,`